# Group by and order by in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to access s3 data using a spark Application. I am applying Spark SQL to retrieve the data. It is not taking group by clause.

```
DataFrame summaryQuery=sql.sql("Select score from summary order by updationDate desc);
summaryQuery.groupBy("sessionId").count().show();
summaryQuery.show();
```

Also i am trying it directly

```
    DataFrame summaryQuery=sql.sql("Select score from summary group by sessionId order by updationDate desc);
summaryquery.show();
```

But in both the cases i am getting SQL exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'score' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Please specify how can i query the data.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? your group by column should be present in your select query and you need to apply aggregate function. please post your sample input and output dataset , so that we will help you to achieve the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Spark SQL, We have to wrap it in a function either first(column_name) or last(column_name) or any aggregate function when column_name is not present in group by clause. It will take either first or last value from the fetched rows respectively.

```
DataFrame summaryQuery=sql.sql("Select first(score) from summary group by sessionId order by updationDate desc);
summaryquery.show();
```